# How to have two authors in harvard style in a single bracket

Tags: biblatex, biber

So, I try to get a citation of several authors into one bracket for the harvard citation style.

I use

`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,]{biblatex}`

For normal citations i use

`\parencite[S. 242]{baeriswyl2003}`

to get an outcome like:

> als Siedlung mit städtischen Strukturen(Baeriswyl 2003, S. 242).

What I want to achieve is the following:

For several authors in one citation like

> bereits von mehreren Authoren behandelt wurden (Baeriswyl 2003, S. 233; Liedke 1984, S. 22; Hecht 2007, S. 16).

**and** If I want to have two authors in one bracket for a comparison something like:

> ...wie es auch an den Sandtnermodellen zu erkennen ist (Vgl. Baeriswyl 2003, S. 246; Liedke 1984, T. 6a).

How do I have to cite the two described cases to get the desired outcome?

The bibfile entries look like this:

```
@book{liedke1984,
    author = {Liedke, V.},
    title = {Das Bürgerhaus in Altbaiern},
    series = {Das deutsche Bürgerhaus},
    volume = {XXXIII},
    publisher = {Verlag Ernst Wasmuth},
    year = {1984},
    address = {Tübingen},
}

@book{baeriswyl2003,
    author = {Baeriswyl, A.},
    title = {Stadt, Vorstadt und Stadterweiterung im Mittelalter archäologische und historische Studien zum Wachstum der drei Zähringerstädte Burgdorf, Bern und Freiburg im Breisgau},
    series = {Schweizer Beiträge zur Kulturgeschichte und Archäologie des Mittelalters},
    volume = {30},
    publisher = {Schweizerischer Burgenverein},
    year = {2003},
    address = {Basel},
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the critical comment, since I'm quite new to latex I will take my time an try my best to edit my post as mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need page references you can just write several keys into the same pair of curly braces

```
\autocite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}
```

If you want page references, you need to use the multicite version of the `\...cite` command, which is normally called `\...cites` with an **`s`**. Then you can give multiple works with pre- and postnote as follows

```
\autocites(<global pre>)(<global post>)[<pre>][<post>]{<key 1>}[<pre>][<post>]{<key 2>}...[<pre>][<post>]{<key n>}
```

e.g.

```
\autocites(vgl.)()[380]{sigfridsson}[12-23]{nussbaum}
\autocites[380]{sigfridsson}[12-23]{nussbaum}[45]{worman}
```

Note that you don't need the "S." prefix in the postnote, `biblatex` can add it automatically. I used `\autocite` instead of `\parencite`, but the general strategy applies for all standard citation commands.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite[380]{sigfridsson}

\autocite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}

\autocites(vgl.)()[380]{sigfridsson}[12-23]{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson und Ryde 1998, S. 380)//(Sigfridsson und Ryde 1998; Nussbaum 1978)//(vgl. Sigfridsson und Ryde 1998, S. 380; Nussbaum 1978, S. 12–23)]

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I will try your mentioned methods and ask for further information or post my successful method here!